# Portable Eclipse and Google Plugins

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I made a portable Eclipse, which loads JDK from relative path i.e. `./JDK`
Also have made Maven to have its `m2repo` in relative path too. It works however I cannot set the Google Plugins, i.e `GWT` and `App Engine` to load from relative path. Is there a way to get around this?

I am getting `IClasspathEntry must be absolute` error when doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [classpath variables](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fbuildpath%2Fref-preferences-classpath-variables.htm) to make relative references.